# How to do a "Tree search" style fit in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to apply the following algorithm to how I'm fitting my model

1. Train the model for X epochs
2. Select the best model from those X epochs
3. Train N models starting from the best model to come from the first fit
4. Train another N models on M of the most successful networks
5. Continue expanding this tree for G generations and take the best model out of all the fitting attempts

I'm a beginner and have no idea of where to start so some help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: start from the start: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/

Comment: By beginner I mean I have a basic understanding of tensorflow and keras I just lack the ability to do anything novel. I've already looked through the tutorials and found nothing relevant.